# Merging or joining two table with records

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem like is, we have two tables t1 and t2. t1 have 3 columns and t2 have 2 columns respectively. suppose t1 have 5 records and t2 have 3 records. I want to merge or join both the tables such that records of t2 comes in table t1 after last record. we can make columns like that T1(c1, c2, c3) and T2(c2,c3) where c2 and c3 are same data types  in both the tables and c1 makes as primary or unique key.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here, cause your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  My guess is you want all the records from table 2 to be listed after all the records from table one.  In that case, use a "UNION ALL" command

Comment: There is no concept of "after" in a SQL table.  Do you mean that these tables have higher valued primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an UNIQUE ALL statement (an normal union without "all" returns only distinct values).

```
select c1, c2, c3 from t1
union all 
select null as c1, c2, c3 from t2
```

Comment: What is Access (if not a DBMS)?

Comment: And why do you provide an answer that (you think) it doesn't work?

Comment: first things first: my database teacher seperated data base management systems (DBMS) like oracle, mssql or mysql and simple Data Base Systems (DBS) like access. wikipedia might say other things. i've edited my answer.

Comment: second: i didn't notice the tags. the thread owner uses "oracle" as tag but i've only read the text. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all the rows from the two tables with the rows from T1 appearing before those of T2.

```
select c1, c2, c3 from t1 
union all  
select null as c1, c2, c3 from t2 
order by nvl2(c1, 0, 1) asc
```

The NVL2() command will return 0 when the value for C1 is not null; this is true  for all the rows in T1 (it's the primary key) and false for all the rows in T2.  The order with the tables is arbitrary, but can be fixed by adding additional columns to the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

If understand your post correctly, you want to append the records that can be found in table `t2` to table `t1`.

```
insert into t1 (c1, c2, c3) (select sequence_for_t1.nextval, c2, c3 from t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
UNION
```

For merging records of more then one table